# Maven. Set java.library.path

Tags: java, maven, applet, java-native-interface, jnlp

How I can set `java.library.path` in applet using Maven?  Usually we can set it by passing parameters to JVM: `-Djava.library.path=path/path2`. But how I can cause applet to load native libs from `java.library.path` **specified by me**?

**P.S.** I use 3rd-party Java lib, which uses native `.dll`. So I think it useless to try preload native lib using `System.loadLibrary(relativePath);` (because 3rd-party lib in any case retry to load .dll from `java.library.path` and then throw `UnsatisfiedLinkError`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can set `java.library.path` in applet using Maven?

AFIAU it is not necessary to specify a path so long as the native is on the run-time class-path of the app.  Putting it into the root of a Jar referenced as a `nativelib` in the JNLP should do that.

Comment: hmm, it's strange, but I put `.dll` in `resources` package (of maven project), so this .dll 100% inside classpath, and is located in root of the jar.. But I still get `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Comment: resolved, forget to change `<jar href...>` to `<nativelib href...>` . Thanks. I hope this change not expose my .jar to some additonal restrictions?

Comment: *"hope this change not expose my .jar to some additonal restrictions?"* Not as far as I know.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the java.library.path for `Maven` this way as this is something you set when the program is run, not when it is built.

For an applet the `PATH` for windows or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` must be set correctly before the browser starts.

Otherwise you need to use the absolute path and search for the DLL or SO yourself.

BTW: You may have security problems trying to use a shared library from an applet.